# Generate HTTPS link when behind Load Balancer that terminates SSL

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

My setup as below:-

1. LB (that terminates SSL)
2. LB then forward the request to my app over port 80

Nginx didnt know it is behind load-balancer. For now all relative href in my static HTML e.g `<a href="/about-us">About Us</a>` will be link to
`http://server/about-us`

My expected result is for Nginx to set/force all links to HTTPS.
My app is Nuxt.js static file, generated using nuxt generate.

My Nginx conf as below:-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /www/data/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.html;

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Edit: I noticed the href generated nicely with https. But when the href didnt contain trailing slash, the server will try to append using `try_files` rules.
At this point, it will append the trailing slash but changed the scheme to http since to Nginx it is serving http request (not https)

Thx.

Comment: Remove the `$uri/` term from `try_files` to stop Nginx generating the redirect. Alternatively, use `absolute_redirect off;` to prevent Nginx adding `http:` so that the browser can decide for itself.

Comment: The absolute_redirect did the tricks. Just need to clear cache to make it work